# pandas how to count the number of rows whose column values add up to a threshold

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`,

```
pct    id
0.3    631
0.2    115
0.1    312
0.2    581
0.01   574
0.09   586
```

I want to first sort the `df` by `pct`,

```
df.sort_values(by=['pct'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

then adding up `pct` to 0.8 and count how many rows does that, e.g. top 4 rows in this case; I am wondering whats the best way to it. using `pd.eval` or `pd.query`?

Comment: `and count how many rows does that` what do you mean? Could you add the expected output?

Comment: `df['pct'].cumsum().le(.8).sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cumulative sum  by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) like mentioned @Chris A and if need count number of rows use `sum`:

```
out = df['pct'].cumsum().lt(0.8).sum()
print (out)
4
```

Or filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['pct'].cumsum().lt(0.8)]
print (df1)
   pct   id
0  0.3  631
1  0.2  115
3  0.2  581
2  0.1  312
```